Transparent pixels on png file are black
I am texturing a model. The transparent pixels are black. I cant fix it. (Fixed the blurry textures)



Edit: It renders correctly in the texture paint tab.


If you are in Eevee you need to go into the Material panel > Settings > Blend Mode > Alpha Blend, if it's not the problem, please share your file

How do I get to settings from the material panel?

If you are in Eevee you need to go into the Material panel > Settings > Blend Mode > Alpha Blend. Also you need to plug the Alpha output of your Image Texture node into the Alpha input of your Principled BSDF.


Doing alpha blend then adjusting the alpha slider makes it aither complete opacue and black background or everyhting becomes slightly transparent until it is fully invisible. I will share the file but i dont know how. (Its an obj with textures)

Pack the images (file > external data > pack resources) and share on workupload for example

also in your material you need to plug the Alpha output of your Image Texture node into the Alpha input of your Principled BSDF

it worked, thanks

Alpha clip with the clipp threshold worked better
